# ANDROID AVD "emulator" package must be installed

Tags: android, docker, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, avd-manager

I want install new device in my docker container.

I had dowload new sdk

```
./sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
```

I had accept all licences

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

And now I want create a new emulator with AVDMANAGER

```
./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" --abi google_apis/x86 --force
```

When I launch command, I have this message

```
Do you wish to create a custom hardware profile? [no]
```

I press `yes` and I have this error

```
Error: "emulator" package must be installed!
```

Can you explain me how I can install this package ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is:

```
./sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator
```